# How to create resolution clauses for overloaded interface methods?

Tags: delphi, interface

Let's say I have an interface like this one:

```
IMaker = interface
  function Make(const Int: Integer): IInterface; overload;
  function Make(const Str: String): IInterface; overload;
end;
```

The common way to implement this interface looks like this:

```
TMaker = class(TInterfacedObject, IMaker)
public
  function Make(const Int: Integer): IInterface; overload;
  function Make(const Str: String): IInterface; overload;
end;
```

But what if I want to use [method resolution clauses](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Method_Resolution_Clause) for some reasons? My first guess looks like this:

```
TMaker = class(TInterfacedObject, IMaker)
private
  function MakeByInt(const Int: Integer): IInterface; 
  function MakeByStr(const Str: String): IInterface; 
public
  function IMaker.Make(const Int: Integer) = MakeByInt;
  function IMaker.Make(const Str: String) = MakeByStr;
end;
```

This code doesn't compile since parameter lists are not allowed in method resolution clauses.

**How does the syntax look like in this case? Is it even possible to use method resolution clauses for overloaded methods?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question stated the answer:

> parameter lists are not allowed in method resolution clauses

Parameter lists are necessary for resolving overloads, and since you can't specify parameter lists in method resolution clauses, you cannot use method resolution clauses for overloaded methods.  There is no syntax to support what you are asking for.

Comment: In other words: **it is a bad idea to overload methods in interfaces**. Use different names and all is well.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis there is nothing wrong with using overloads in interfaces in general. Obviously the compiler supports it. You just can't use *this particular feature* with overloads.

Comment: The compiler supports it, but it is generally **not a good idea**.